# convert ascii to binary and write to a binary file - PYTHON 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to read binary file (like .bmp or .jpg) and convert each binary data to ascii and do multiplication (like ascii * 2) and convert back to binary format and write to a new file.

I wrote the program as below

```
    filename = input("enter file to read: ")
    readfile = filename + ".bmp"
    writefilebmp = filename + '1' + ".bmp"
    fr = open(readfile,"rb");
    fwbmp = open(writefilebmp,"wb");
    bytes_read = fr.read(1024)
    for b in bytes_read:
        print(b,end='')
        data = b*2;
        fwbmp.write(data)
    fr.close()
    fwbmp.close()
```

But i'm getting the below error

**TypeError: 'int' does not support the buffer interface**

Note: Once i the solution, i will modify the code to skip the bmp or jpeg header

**Modified**

```
    filename = input("enter file to read: ")
    readfile = filename + ".bmp"
    writefilebmp = filename + '1' + ".bmp"
    fr = open(readfile,"rb");
    fwbmp = open(writefilebmp,"wb");
    bytes_read = fr.read(20)
    for b in bytes_read:
        print(b,end='')
        data = b*2;
        fwbmp.write(bytes(data))
    fr.close()
    fwbmp.close()
```

Comment: What do you hope to achieve by doing this?

Comment: i do have a requirement where all the pixels are very near to black (max of 20), i need to do pixel doubling on this...

Comment: And this isn't something that'd be easier by using [Pillow?](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.0.0) (bearing in mind you're dealing with image files and pixel data...)

Comment: I changed my program as above (modified), i see only 0's in the output file

Comment: Please **give up this approach** - look at image manipulation libraries as I've already said. It may take an hour to get to grips with one, but you've already wasted 41mins so far on this which will go nowhere...

Comment: If you want to increase the contrast in an image, then please use an image library that will do this for you. It's not as easy as you think. If you are doing this to learn Python, then continue.

Comment: i need to lot of exploring on Pillow, as i now my only rquirement is thi, i think it will save my time @JonClements

Comment: @Sathya feel free - but you've asked for help and have been advised you're going nowhere with this approach... So unless someone here is going to give you an answer or panda to your strange approach, then you're going to have to work out how to fix this yourself...

Comment: @Sathya: Forget Pillow. Install ImageMagick. Then do this: `mogrify -normalize *` (copy the images first, this manipulates the filed directly). There, you have now maximized the contrast of all the pictures in your directory. Done.

Comment: @LennartRegebro that works as well :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looping over bytes, which gives you integers. Convert back to bytes to write to a binary file:

```
fwbmp.write(bytes([data % 256]))
```

The modulo 256 is required here to limit the resulting int value to a permissible value. You could also cap the value at 255 with `min()`:

```
fwbmp.write(bytes([min(data, 255)]))
```

or you could write *two* bytes if your doubling results in an overflow:

```
if data > 255:
    fwbmp.write(bytes(divmod(data, 256)))
else:
    fwbmp.write(bytes([data]))
```

or always produce 2 bytes regardless, where the first byte is either `0x01` or `0x00`:

```
fwbmp.write(bytes(divmod(data, 256)))
```

You'll need to decide what you want your 'doubling' to mean in terms of output.

Comment: They could, but then if they want to multiple by 2, 254 * 2 is not 255 nor 252... I'm not sure the OP actually wants to do anything like this at all... :P

Comment: The later is more likely - which came a little while after my initial comment - however, then we're getting to `struct.pack` or `int.to_bytes` if possible... And good luck to anyone reading back what might be one byte or two byte :)

Comment: @MartijnPieters i tried, fwbmp.write(bytes(data)) (since my data won't go beyond 256), but in the output file, i see only NULL

Comment: @Sathya: `bytes(0)` will writes NULLs, yes. Are you certain your **input** is not null as well?

Comment: @Sathya: ah, `bytes(0)` is an empty bytestring, `bytes([0])` is one byte hex value 00. Corrected.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks a lot... i missed [], by putting fwbmp.write(bytes([data])) it stated working